# Parsing double from file in C

Tags: c, parsing, scanf

I have the following code to read tabulated numbers from a file, but fscanf returns with -1. Whar am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
FILE *in;
if (argc != 2) {
  fprintf(stderr,"Wrong number of parameters.\n");
  fprintf(stderr,"Please give the path of input file.\n");
  return 1;
}
if((in = fopen(argv[1],"r")) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"\'%s\' cannot be opened.\n",argv[1]);
}
int lines = 0;
char c;
while( (c=fgetc(in)) != EOF) {
    if(c == '\n') {lines++;}
}
printf("%d lines\n",lines);
int i = 0;
double a, b;
double x[lines], y[lines];
for(i; i < lines; i++) {
    if(fscanf(in,"%lf %lf", &a, &b) != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Wrong input format.\n");
    }
    printf("%lf %lf",a,b);
}
return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

}

Comment: Unrelated: Unless the *last* `'\n'` is the *last* char in the file, your line count will be off by one. Related: You just sent `in` all the way to EOF. What do you think it will be `fscanf()`-ing?

Comment: Input, expected behavior, observed behavior, and line with error.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I'm counting on it, the file is prepared for that.

Comment: Note: best to use `int c` rather than `char c` to avoid false detection of EOF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read entire file to find the number of lines..so at the end file pointer has reached the end.. What do you think happens when you call 'fscanf' again ??

You need to reset your file pointer to start again

```
printf("%d lines\n",lines);
rewind(in);
int i = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You already read the file completely using `fgetc` so by the time you call `fscanf` the reading pointer is already at the end of the file.

You can manually place the read pointer at the beginning by using

```
fseek(in, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

in front of your loop.